# Polymer 3.0 multi-select similar to select2 library multi-select

Tags: polymer, jquery-select2

Is there any component in polymer 3.0 which is similar to select2(library) multi-select.
I tried multiple packages but its not similar to select2.The goal is to view all selected items in boxes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlFBm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to just get select2 working inside Poylmer 3, and then making your own component.

From searching around there is no "silver bullet" component that you can plug and play that is as polished as select2. There are a few components on webcomponents.org that might be close at least. ( But no where near what select2 offers )

some to check out:

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Neovici/paper-autocomplete-chips

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/mastercodekw/mcd-multi-select
( Not quite select2 style but depending on your use case, might be an option )

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerEl/paper-tags
( Not very polished )

I hope this helps